# ngChange in custom directive fire twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Attached custom directive that let using ng-change as attribute.

The problem is, when I using it twice in the same view, I notice that bar method fire twice, I found the problem that the `$viewChangeListeners` store the same method of the controller twice. Note: notice that maybe I've the same directive twice with two different ng-change methods

Have any one any idea to get over this problem?

HTML:

```
<my-directive ng-model="foo"  items="items" ng-change="bar1(foo)"></my-directive>
<my-directive ng-model="foo2" items="items" ng-change="bar2(foo2)"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="updateModel(item)">{{item}}</div>',
require: "ngModel",
scope : {
  items : "="
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
  scope.updateModel = function(item)
  {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
  }
  ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
    scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
  });
}
```

[plunkr sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/uKwSJTtZMqBZPju0PANL?p=preview)

Try this one, click on the up (1), then click on the down (1), then click on the up (1). The events fires as following: bar1, bar2, bar1, bar2

Comment: Sorry about that, included!

Comment: How do you reckon it fires in that way? I checked it and i think when you click upper 1 for the second time it does not fire (as it has not changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your custom input directive "supports" `ngModel` - that is to say that it uses the `ngModel` pipeline to set the view value - it automatically gets the benefit of supporting other directives that use `ngModel`, like `ng-required`, `ng-maxlength`, ***and*** `ng-change`.

And so, the following **is not needed**:

```
ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
   scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
});
```

In your particular example it actually does not fire `bar1()`/`bar2()` handlers twice, because `scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange)` is evaluated inside the isolate scope that doesn't have `bar1()` and `bar2()`. So, perhaps that happened in your testing before you used the isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but couldn't find a solution on this site or elsewhere. In my case, null was being sent as the value in the additional function call. So my workaround is to handle null in my function:

```
$scope.bar1 = function(foo){
  if(foo != null){
    //perform the task
  }
};
```